# In AnyLogic, how to create a changing, shared resource?

Tags: resources, anylogic

A fake example that emulates what I am trying to accomplish is the following:

I am emulating a restaurant that has employees.
There are three sinks for washing dishes.

The "Number of Employees" required to run the sinks uses this formula:
Number of Employees = (Number of Sinks) + 2

This is because there are some efficiencies in the workflow when multiple sinks are being used at the same time.

I have a resource for employees and an agent (population) to represent the 3 sinks.
When a new sink starts to get used, I check to see the "Number of Employees" currently "busy". I then calculate how many additional workers would be needed to be seized.

The problem I am running into is when a sink stops being used the "Number of Employees" required may change as well. I now need to release that many employees, in order to accurately reflect the required "Number of Employees". The "release" block; however, releases the entirety of the "seize" block. This may be more than the employees that should be released.

Is there an easier way to manage a changing shared resource?
Or if this is a good way, how do you manage the releasing of individual employees not the entire seize block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is not absolutely correct:

> The "release" block; however, releases the entirety of the "seize"
> block. This may be more than the employees that should be released.

If you go to the release block, you will see that you have the option to release a specific number of resources of a given pool. Moreover, that number is dynamic so it can be a function with the number of sinks as an input.

I think the trick is that you MAY need more than one release blocks that are consecutive, one for employees and one for sinks, depending on your model design.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Emile! I didn't realize there was that option.